# Implement Google Plus Plugin on PhoneGap 3.3

Tags: cordova

I have a problem with implement Google Plus login  on PhoneGap.

I already go this far :

1) I register my app on developer.google.com
It return for me like this :

Client ID for native application

Client ID : 
    1045340154880-mgirmj2jopmvbc7unrduts9crh29qrev.apps.googleusercontent.com

Client secret : 
    JSWK5DfBcAhVUild9G53nJhr

Redirect URIs :
        urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
        loca lhost

2) And then, i created a JS file like this link stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap

My config look like :

client_id: '1045340154880-mgirmj2jopmvbc7unrduts9crh29qrev.apps.googleusercontent.com',

client_secret: 'JSWK5DfBcAhVUild9G53nJhr',

redirect_uri: 'loca lhost',

scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'

3) And then, i can logged in, but When i try to click Accept Button to let my app access through account, it call back loca lhost and say : The webpage is not available

4) After that, i change my config back to redirect_uri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' instead of local host, this time it say : Please copy the code, switch to your application and paste this code into it [code line]

I really don't know what to do now, please hint me !

Any help would be appreciate ! Thank you !!

Comment: sorry, i can't type localhost so...please understand it is http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is need for a **loadstart** event?

```
$(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
var url = e.originalEvent.url;
var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

if (code || error) {
  authWindow.close();
}
```

[taken from PhoneGap Tips](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html)

Note that it says:

> If we try the OAuth flow again with this redirect URI, we see that granting access redirects us to `http://localhost?code=your_authorization_code`. Denying access redirects us to `http://localhost?error=access_denied`. We probably don’t have an HTTP server running on our mobile device, so we will most likely end up staring at some sort of error page, but it doesn’t matter because we can detect the authorization code in the loadstart event handler and close the InAppBrowser before any errors are displayed.

Comment: thank you very much for answering me, i already have this code, but when i run as debug, it say "Permission denied" at this line $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {

Comment: I can't help you more without having you add the relevant code and any relevant debug output you get.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time to help me. This is my error : 0x800a0046 - JavaScript runtime error: Permission denied. And i do exactly like the tutorial above, but the error occur when the code run to $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function (e) { . Do you have any idea ?